# Swift: Hpple integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am trying for a few hours to integrate Hpple into a new Swift project but with no success. There are 6 files TFHpple.h TFHpple.m, TFHppleElement.h TFHppleElement.m and TFHppleElement.h TFHppleElement.m which i copy to the project.

Being a project written in Swift i declare the three .h files in a -Bridging-Header.h so i can use them written in Objective-C. I don't get any errors with TFHpple.h but the other two classes give out an errors for every variable declared:

> Unknown type name 'NSArray'

What could be the problem ?

This is my Brigging-Header.h

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "TFHpple.h"
#import "TFHppleElement.h"
#import "XPathQuery.h"
```

Comment: BTW, did you add `import Foundation` in Swift file?

Comment: Yes, i did import Foundation in my ViewController swift file.

Answer (score 3):

Miguelb got this right but here is the full detail.

I solved this exact problem with Hpple by adding the following line to the start of the XPathQuery.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Then it would compile fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I would guess that you might have a configuration issue.
Some things to verify:

- Make sure your bridging file is properly named : 
  *e.g. MyProductName-Bridging-Header.h*
- In your Build Settings, make sure you have the full path to your Bridging Header in the **Objective-C Bridging Header** setting. 
  See here for more information: [Importing Objective-C into Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75)
- Also from the documentation: *"Any public Objective-C headers listed in this bridging header file will be visible to Swift"* So I would make sure what you're trying to access is public.
- Make sure there are no other dependencies for the library besides the three headers you mentioned.